# How to get just the function name and alias from CloudFormation AWS::Lambda::Alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I need to set a stage variable for an API Gateway stage. This stage variable has to be just the lambda function and alias (Foo:dev). It cannot be the full ARN. The variable is then used in swagger to integrate API Gateway with a lambda function with a specific alias.

It looks like the only thing I can out of AWS::Lambda::Alias resource is the ARN. How do I just get the name and alias?

This is the stage resource. "lamdaAlias" gets set to the full ARN of the alias.

```
    "ApiGatewayStageDev": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
        "Properties": {
            "StageName": "dev",
            "Description": "Dev Stage",
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "ApiGatewayApi"
            },
            "DeploymentId": {
                "Ref": "ApiGatewayDeployment"
            },
            "Variables": {
                "lambdaAlias": {
                    "Ref": "LambdaAliasDev"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reuse the same values used to specify the `FunctionName` and `Name` properties in the [`AWS::Lambda::Alias`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-alias.html) resource. For example, assuming your resource is specified like this in your template:

```
"LambdaAliasDev" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Alias",
  "Properties" : {
    "FunctionName" : { "Ref" : "MyFunction" },
    "FunctionVersion" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "TestingNewFeature", "Version" ] },
    "Name" : { "Ref" : "MyFunctionAlias" }
  }
}
```

You would combine the function and alias into a single string using the [`Fn::Join`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) intrinsic function, like this:

```
"ApiGatewayStageDev": {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
    "Properties": {
        "StageName": "dev",
        "Description": "Dev Stage",
        "RestApiId": {
            "Ref": "ApiGatewayApi"
        },
        "DeploymentId": {
            "Ref": "ApiGatewayDeployment"
        },
        "Variables": {
            "lambdaAlias": {
                "Fn::Join": {[ ":", [
                  { "Ref": "MyFunction" },
                  { "Ref": "MyFunctionAlias" }
                ]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `MyFunction` is `Foo` and `MyFunctionAlias` is `dev`, this would set `lambdaAlias` to `Foo:dev` as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show how you would define MyFunctionAlias (assuming it's not a parameter)?

Comment: @boris `MyFunctionAlias` is a parameter in this example- see the [Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) documentation for how to define parameters in a stack template. If you want to specify the value as a fixed constant instead, either create a parameter with a default value, or replace `{ "Ref": "MyFunctionAlias" }` with a constant string (e.g., `"dev"`) in both places in the template.